# SP 2010 List Alerts Not Working on Added Content Types?

Tags: list, content-type, alert

I have been trying to add an alert for any changes on an item that is created on a list. However I have added a new content type to the list and removed the default item content type. When I set the alert all I get is an email saying that I was subscribed to that list and no emails were sent at all for any new items or items modified. After doing some troubleshooting I discovered that the alerts will work on the default "item" content type on the list but not only any items associated with content types that I added to list, even if I make them the default content type. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that having more than one meta data column in your list causes a bug in sharepoint to not send alerts. However if you only have 1 meta data column in the list it will send alerts.